# SWTBot in eclipse- How to find a project's popup menu (right click menu)

Tags: java, swtbot

In my SWTBot test, I'm trying to open (and click) the menu that appears when right clicking on the open project in project explorer (the menu that contains New, Refactor, Import etc.)

I tried to use

```
`treeItem.contextMenu("Refactor").menu("Rename...").click();
```

and got `WidgetNotFoundException`.

help please.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently a known bug in SWTBot ...

You cannot access sub-menus of the context menu. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=261360

2 alternatives :

- ... pressShortcut(SWT.ALT | SWT.SHIFT, 'R')
- bot.menu("Refactor").menu("Rename...").click();

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a now native function:

```
new SWTBotMenu(ContextMenuHelper.contextMenu(bot.tree(), "Refactor", "Rename...")).click();
```

Comment: this approach does not seems to work:                                                   'new SWTBotMenu(ContextMenuHelper.contextMenu(project, "**Run As**"));` -> works fine, However                                                                                                                                                      new SWTBotMenu(ContextMenuHelper.contextMenu(project, "**Run As**", "**Run Configurations...**")); - > Widget Not Found